# Convert a float number to char array on C

Tags: c, floating-point, char, type-conversion, microcontroller

I am trying to convert a float number to a char array.
`sprintf()` will not work for me and neither will `dtostrf`.
Since I have a limit in the decimal number (it is 5) I tried this:

```
    int num = f;
    int decimales = (f-num)*10000;
```

Everything worked fine until I typed the number 123.050. Instead of giving me the decimal part as "0.50" it gives me a 5000, because it does not count the 0 now that my "decimal" variable is an `int`.

Is there any other way to convert it?

Comment: You have no floating point number. You have two `int` values... Declare your float and use `int chars_reqd = snprintf (NULL, 0, "%.5f", fvalue);` then allocate `chars_reqd + 1` characters or use a fixed array such as `char floatstr[64];` and `sprintf (floatstr, "%.5f", fvalue);`

Comment: using sprintf(cad,"%.5f", f) doesn't work for you either?

Comment: (a) Explain why `sprintf` will not work for you. (b) Explain completely the output you want. Should the fraction part always have exactly five digits? At most 5? Is there a limit on the integer part? What about very large (1e300) or very small (1e-300) numbers. What about negative numbers? (c) 10000 times .05 is 500, not 5000. Is the error in your example in the 10000, the 5000, or something else? (d) Should numbers be rounded or truncated to five decimal digits? Do small errors in rounding or truncation matter?

Comment: Please confirm you want 4 decimals, as the `10000` suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a quick and dirty way to produce a string with the decimal representation of your float without linking `sprintf` because of space constraints on an embedded system. The number of decimals is fixed. Here is a proposal:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *ftoa(char *dest, size_t size, double val, int dec) {
    char *p = dest;
    char *q = dest + size;
    long long mul = 1;
    long long num;
    int i;
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;
    *--q = '\0';
    if (size == 1)
        goto fail;
    if (val < 0) {
        val = -val;
        if (p >= q)
            goto fail;
        *p++ = '-';
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dec; i++) {
        mul *= 10;
    }
    num = (long long)(val * mul + 0.5);
    for (i = 1; i < dec + 2 || num > 0; i++) {
        if (p >= q)
            goto fail;
        *--q = '0' + (num % 10);
        num = num / 10;
        if (i == dec) {
            if (p >= q)
                goto fail;
            *--q = '.';
        }
    }
    memmove(p, q, dest + size - q);
    return dest;
fail:
    return memset(dest, '*', size - 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[24];

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        double d = strtod(argv[i], NULL);
        int dec = 5;
        if (i + 1 < argc)
            dec = atoi(argv[++i]);
        printf("%s\n", ftoa(buf, sizeof buf, d, dec));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `num = (long long)(val * mul + 0.5);` can fail to provide the best result when `val * mul + 0.5` is inexact.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: you are correct, the above is a very simplistic approach to the problem. A complete solution is to say the least *non trivial*. I should refine the answer with limitations for this function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%04d` in `printf()`

```
 const int D4 = 10000;

 double f = 123.050;
 int i = round(f*D4);
 int num = i / D4;
 int decimales = i % D4;
 printf("%d.%04d\n", num, decimales);
```

gives

```
123.0500
```

If you worry about an `int` overflow (since we multiply the number by `10000`), use `long`, or `long long` instead...

To save decimals in a string including the leading zero(es)

```
char sdec[5];
sprintf(sdec, "%04d", decimales);
```

`sdec` contains the decimals, including the leading zero.

(see also [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) )

Comment: ok.. but is there any way that my decimal variable saves that leading 0?

Comment: This answer is premature. There are errors and omissions in the question regarding the number of digits wanted, the precise formatting, and the rounding desired. Additionally, this answer is sloppy: Multiplying by rounding 10000 introduces rounding errors, and the code in this answer truncates where it may be desired to round. Note that `(f-num + 0.0000001)` can cause the fraction part to exceed 1, causing an incorrect display.

Comment: `round((f-num)*10000)` will cause 123.99996… to be displayed as “123.10000”.

Comment: Which I would want for this program ... usually you want to round....

Comment: No, if rounding is being used, 123.99996… should display as “124.0000”. “123.10000” is wrong.